# Obtain $v_y(y)$ equation for an object dropped from some height taking air resistance into account

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, drag

For an object that is dropped from some height, taking air resistance $f=kv$ into account we have $\sum F_y=ma_y=mg-kv$. If we rewrite $a_y = \frac{dv_y}{dt}$ we have $m\frac{dv_y}{dt}=mg-kv$. Also, if we let $a_y=0$ we get the terminal velocity $v_t=\frac{mg}{k}$.

Solving this we get $v_y=v_t(1-e^{-(k/m)t})$

If we differentiate this, we get $ a_y = g e ^{-(k/m)t}$

And also integrating $v_y$ with respect to $t$ we get $y = v_t\left(t-\frac{m}{k}(1-e^{-(k/m)t}\right)$.

This is all correct, as it is directly from a textbook.

What I am after is a $v_y(y)$ equation, that relates the speed and the vertical displacement, like the equation ${v_y}^2= {u_y}^2+2ay$ in the case of constant acceleration.

The only way I can think of is to obtain an expression for $t$ in terms of $y$ from $y = v_t\left(t-\frac{m}{k}(1-e^{-(k/m)t}\right)$ and substitute this expression for $t$ into $v_y=v_t(1-e^{-(k/m)t})$, but I don't know how to subject $t$.

Is this even possible? Is there a way you can obtain the $v_y(y)$ equation?
Thanks..

Comment: To see where this might be going, try to isolate $t$ from the $v_y$ equation and insert this into the $y$ formula. That gives you an equation without $t$, BUT...

Comment: try this $\dfrac{dv}{dy}=\dfrac{\dfrac{dv}{dt}}{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}=\dfrac{mg-kv}{v}$